# Data grid view in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, datagridview

I am looking for Data grid view for eclipse like there is c#
any suggestion ? does there is something in org.eclipse.swt?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) describes the component list available in [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/intro.html).

For [GridView](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/10185-grid-view-in-java.html) you can choose [JTable](http://swingx.java.net/).

Comment: In the standard dataGridView in C# you can you have the property datasource for the load data dynamic, Does JTable have something like that?

Comment: tutorial link is dead, and so is the GridView link

Answer (score 0):

*[C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)* is a programming language while *[eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)* on the other hand is an *[IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)*.
You are looking for *[Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/overview/intro.html)* or *[Awt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html)* in *[java](http://www.java.com/)*.

Comment: you are right (I'm new in Java) do you know about something like that in Swing or Awt ?